# Finding open files

Tags: usb, windows-vista

I'm using Windows Vista with an external (USB) hard drive.  Sometimes I need to disconnect the hard drive, but when I try to disconnect USB devices, Windows tells me that an application is using the files on that drive.  As far as I know, I have closed anything accessing the hard drive.

Is there a way to determine which files are in use, and by which process?

**Edit**

Apparently (according to the [OpenedFilesView website](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html)) it makes a difference that I have a 64-bit version of Vista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) does exactly what you need, and many other useful diagnostic features as well. I highly recommend it.

here's a tutorial:

**[How to: Display a List of Processes That Have Files Open](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242131)**, using Process Explorer

Comment: i much prefer Anvir Task Manager over Process Explorer, even the free version beats PE hands down.

Comment: I'm curious then... why didn't you link Anvir Task manager as an answer to this question? Does it lack the ability to view open file handles?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to determine which
>   files are in use, and by which
>   process?

NirSoft's **[OpenedFilesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/opened_files_view.html)** displays the list of all opened files on your system. For each opened file, additional information is displayed: handle value, read/write/delete access, file position, the process that opened the file, and more...

[image]

*OpenedFilesView is freeware and portable.*